# Is it possible to directly connect ReactJs with ExpressJs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

My needs are simple, I want the ReactJs frontend served from an ExpressJs server, without crazy separate ports and stuff.

Is it possible to send HTTP requests to my server for APIs as well?

How can I do this?

Comment: I had made a youtube video on this exact topic some time back. see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=03qFJCc8DOA
The motivation for this was that I had to dynamically insert meta tags for SEO purposes and for that I had to serve my app using pm2 which is similar to express.
I thought others might benefit from what I learned so I made this youtube video.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and yes.

You create the react site. Use the dev server to develope it and make it look nice. When its ready you build it by doing

`npm run build`

Then you create the express server and make it serve the static html files

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.use('/', express.static('dist'))

app.listen(3000, () => { console.log('running on 3000') })
```

Now you can open the express app on server 3000 and it serves the react site.

Comment: Should this be inserted into the default index.js?